# Touch friendly OS or desktop environment

Tags: operating-systems, touchscreen

I plan to get a Raspberry PI 2 Model B and the following touchscreen http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00LN9MYCO/

Now my question is, which OS or desktop environment can you recommend with good touch support?

Comment: The better question is which desktop environment to use.

Comment: @alb3rtano0012 thanks for the hint. I edited the question a bit.

Comment: I don't have one of those little touchscreens, but I have noticed a question here before indicating that the major problem is getting the desktop scaled so that it is usable -- i.e., you can probably use any DE, but you will have to configure it.   Once you have the screen you should be able to figure out what's possible with what DE (you can have more than one installed and select between them).   If you don't get a satisfactory answer and you do find a decent solution yourself, please leave your own answer here.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It's my understanding that Raspberry Pi's of all flavors can run Android.  If you want a touch aware OS, that's probably your best bet.</strike>  The OS isn't your only requirement for touch.  The apps and programs should be touch friendly too, and obviously Android delivers there too.

There was a concerted push a few years ago to get Android going. Apparently, that never went anywhere. This article [Android 4.0 is coming!](https://www.raspberrypi.org/android-4-0-is-coming/) give you the official build and story. This page is the unofficial Android + Pi page: [Razdroid Project Wiki](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki) though it seems they don't have much to offer in the performance department yet.

Comment: As per the edit, beware that Android is in a very tenuous state on the pi currently (and may remain so) and you should probably think hard before you become become a playtester of it.

Comment: So, for those like me and unfamiliar with wtf the fool above is talking about, there was a concerted push a few years ago to get Android going.  Apparently, that never went anywhere.  This article https://www.raspberrypi.org/android-4-0-is-coming/ give you the official build and story.  This page is the unofficial Android + Pi page: http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki though it seems they don't have much to offer in the performance department.

Comment: I apologize for being a bit nasty.  Just this was a very misleading answer -- thank you for qualifying it better.

Answer (score 0):

look up sailfish os https://sailpi.wordpress.com/ not sure how good it is but I believe it works with the 7 inch touch screen